# Python declare global class accessible by several modules

Tags: python

If I have a module gobalcfgs containing

```
class Cfgs:
    ...

cfg = Cfgs()
```

is there a way to share this across multiple modules in a project.
I have a main module that import utility modules. So, the import direction is

```
main <-- utility_1.py
main <-- utility_2.py
```

However, some global variables and classed get defined in main and are used in the utility modules. Currently I have them as variables in the function call, but it would be nicer to have a global structure that can be accessed from all modules instead of sending the information over a chain of functions.

so, instead of having something like this in main

```
cfg.sethost(host)
data = utility.getData(cfg)
```

in utility

```
def getData(cfg):
    getDataFromX(cfg):

def getDataFromX(cfg):
    con = openConnection(cfg):

def openConnection(cfg):
    con = mycon(cfg.host)
```

Having cfg being some sort of global and then have in main

```
from globalcfgs import cfg 
cfg.setHost(host)
data = utility.getData()
```

and in utility

```
from globalcfgs import cfg 
def openConnection():    
    con = mycon(cfg.host)
```

This is not exactly a real life example I have but supposed to illustrate that I need to ship information over a long chain of functions. 
Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: `from globals import cfg` – that should do exactly what you want. It'll make `cfg` available as a global name in each module that imports it.

Comment: Rember your "globals" class shadows built-in Python function globals() which is not good practice in general.

Comment: thanks. I cleaned that up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, don't call a class `globals`, as that shadows the built-in `globals()` function. In any case, Python style is that classes use CamelCase - with initial capitals - and functions use `snake_case`.

That apart though, what you have is fine. You can import `cfg` in any module that uses it; the only thing is that you have the import statement the wrong way round, it should be `from globalstuff import cfg`.

Comment: I tried that initially, but it seemed that each module imports its own instantiation of cfg. So, any change I make to cfg in the main module is not reflected in the cfg in the utilities module. Is that how it is meant to be or am I doing something wrong somewhere?

Comment: No, that's not true. If `cfg` is defined inside `gobalcfgs` as an instance of `Cfgs`, and you import it in each module, they will all point to the same instance. The only way it wouldn't be shared is if you are running multiple processes, but that's the same with any data.